# Why my md5 is always different if I launch program a few times?

Tags: c++, openssl, md5

I have a program that encrypt string and compute md5, but if I launch program a few times it prints different results. My program read key from the same file.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    RSA *private_key  =  PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(f, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    unsigned char sourceText[] = "source_string";
    unsigned char *cipher =(unsigned char*) OPENSSL_malloc(RSA_size(private_key));

    int ret = RSA_private_encrypt(strlen((char*)text), text, cipher, private_key, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING);

    unsigned char md5Result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    MD5((unsigned char*)&cipher, strlen((char*) cipher), (unsigned char*)&md5Result);
    printf("md5  %s \n", BN_bn2hex(BN_bin2bn(md5Result, MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH, NULL)));
    return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Post compilable code.

Comment: I am willing to be that the problem lies with the use of `(unsigned char*)&cipher` in the call to `MD5`.. I would suggest changing it to just `cipher`

Comment: @RSahu: It's already an `unsigned char*`, so the cast isn't even necessary.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, noticed that after seeing your answer.

Comment: By the way, there's little C++ in your code. In C++, you are supposed to use `std::string` and interface with C functions via functions like `c_str()`. And you could use `std::cout` instead of `printf`, and `nullptr` instead of `NULL`, and `std::ifstream` instead of `fopen`. In fact, your code looks like C, not C++.

Answer (score 4):

A lot of ugly casting going on here, but it looks like the problem is that you take the address of the local pointer object `cipher` instead of using what it's pointing at. Using `cipher` instead of `(unsigned char*)&cipher` should fix that.